# Sorting objects in a list and Combining values

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have an `std::list<object>` and object has 6 integer and a char array elements in it. I want to sort these objects with a specific integer (lets say integer a) and afterwards, I want to combine char arrays with the sorted order.

Does stl has some kind of method for this specific sorting ? If no, how am i supposed to do for this kind of sorting ?

Answer (score 1):

`std::list::sort` has an overload that takes a custom comparator, as does `std::sort` for more suitable containers. So you can use that for sorting:

```
my_list.sort([](object const & o1, object const & o2) {return o1.a < o2.a;});
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "combine char arrays", but you can iterate over the sorted list with `std::for_each`, `std::transform`, or a simple for loop in order to do something with each object in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own comparator to the sort function or implement operator< for your `object` class. You can find more information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/). Be aware to use `std::list::sort` rather then `std::sort`.

```
// list::sort
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

// comparison, not case sensitive.
bool compare_nocase (const std::string& first, const std::string& second)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    while ( (i<first.length()) && (i<second.length()) )
    {
        if (tolower(first[i])<tolower(second[i])) return true;
            else if (tolower(first[i])>tolower(second[i])) return false;
        ++i;
    }
    return ( first.length() < second.length() );
}

int main ()
{
    std::list<std::string> mylist;
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    mylist.push_back ("one");
    mylist.push_back ("two");
    mylist.push_back ("Three");

    mylist.sort();

    std::cout << "mylist contains:";
    for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    mylist.sort(compare_nocase);

    std::cout << "mylist contains:";
    for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```